# how to monitor the HTML input value changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

We can use  jquery to monitor the html input value change  , but I am confusing if the input value  changed by javascript can we monitor it ? I can not rewrite other person code so I can not add the `focus` and `blur` to monitor the value changing . I have to say it again the input value change by JavaScript，not the keyboard or the mouse.

I have tried it with jquery but I got nothing ,here is the code .

```
 <div style="display:none;" canshow="false"><input 
 name="extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)" value="GT-2013-FT- 
 SZ·G-007-3" type="hidden"></div>
```

```
 $("input[name='extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)']").bind('input 
  porpertychange',function(){
     console.log('666')
  });
```

I write this html for this question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input name="extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)" 
value="Initial value" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change()">change_input_value</a>
</body>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change () {// I suppose this is the function and it can not be 
 rewrited

 $("input[name='extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)']").val("changed 
  value")
    }
    //now show me how to monitor the input value change , you can not alter  the change function
    </script>
   </html>
```

I want the console can show `666` ,actually I need to do something in the bind function . And there are more than 10 input elements ,but I only need to monitor  one input element .  I have to monitor the input value change so that I can do something after it change , do you know what I mean ? Can you give me some advice ?

Comment: `console.log` - `.` not `,`.

Comment: fixed    thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hack, but if you can't alter the other code, one option is to put a getter and setter on the `input` itself, so that the other code's `input.value = ...` and `$(input).val(..)` go through your custom function (rather than invoking the getters and setters of `HTMLInputElement.prototype`):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
// need to save the native getter and setter methods, so they can be invoked later
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
  get() {
    return get.call(this);
  },
  set(newVal) {
    set.call(this, newVal);
    console.log('New value set by JS detected: ', newVal);
    // insert desired functionality here
    return newVal;
  }
});

input.value = 3;
$('input').val(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Another snippet, using your code:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
// need to save the native getter and setter methods, so they can be invoked later
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
  get() {
    return get.call(this);
  },
  set(newVal) {
    set.call(this, newVal);
    console.log('New value set by JS detected: ', newVal);
    // insert desired functionality here
    return newVal;
  }
});


function change() { // I suppose this is the function and it can not be rewrited
  $("input[name='extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)']").val("changed value ")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;">
  <input name="extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)" value="Initial value" type="hidden">
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change()">change_input_value</a>
```

Comment: I completed this question for more detail   just now . Can you show me again ?

Comment: No changes to the code I posted originally are necessary - see edit for a live snippet

Comment: Thank you very much , I change **document.querySelector('input')**  to my input selector , then problem solved

Comment: I find it can use in Chrome but it  does not suit IE , what should I do now ?  I want it can use in IE and Chrome .

Comment: I transpiled it just now , here is the image . And I use it ,but not  suit in IE 9 
https://img.shownmmp.top/babel.png

Comment: IE9 was a *long* time ago... what are the errors it's throwing?

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object not support  “querySelector” attribute or method

Comment: Ha, IE9 doesn't even support `querySelector`, OK. Since you're using jQuery already, you can use the jQuery method instead: `const input = $("input[name='extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)']")[0]`

Comment: Then here comes another error : HTMLInputElement was not defined

Comment: That's odd, MDN says it's [been supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) forever, even by IE. Perhaps you have to explicitly reference it on `window`? `window.HTMLInputElement`?

Comment: Here is my code 

 https://img.shownmmp.top/babel.png
Maybe the follow code 
var _Object$getOwnPropert = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value')

Comment: That's just Babel's way of transpiling out the destructuring assignment, the syntax is fine. Unfortunately, I'm on W10, so I have no way of installing IE9 to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on `change` event.

```
 $("input[name='extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)']").bind('change', function() {
    console.log('666')
 });
```

Or simply call a `change` method.

```
 $("input[name='extendDataFormInfo.value(fd_37157d8be9876e)']").change(function() {
    console.log('666')
 });
```

Comment: This does not listen for changes made by Javascript, which is what OP was asking for.